# Segmentation fault 11, issue using pointers and returning them

Tags: c, pointers, struct, segmentation-fault, return

i keep getting a segmentation fault when running this program. I'm attempting to read the files (inserted into the command line), and allocate the x and y coordinates in each file to a dynamically allocated memory struct called POINTS (using the function called readPoints). After they have been saved into these structs, i then pass them to the function calls calc where the x and y values are multiplied, and then added onto the next x and y multiplied.. so on. Could someone please explain to me where i went wrong! I am not great at pointers.
Thank you in advance.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct
{   
    float xcord;
    float ycord; 
}POINTS;

int readPoints(char* file, int numofpoints);
int calc(POINTS* points, int numofpoints);

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{   

int numoffiles;
FILE* file; 
int result, i;
numoffiles = argc;

POINTS* pointer;
int numofpoints;

if(numoffiles == 1)
{   
    printf("Please enter a file\n");
}

for(i=1; i<numoffiles; i++)
{   
    file = fopen(argv[i], "r");
    fscanf(file, "%d", &numofpoints);
    pointer = readPoints(file, numofpoints);

    if( pointer == NULL)
    {   
        printf("Error return from readPoints function");
    }


    result = calc(&pointer[i], numoffiles);


    printf("%12f", result);
    free(pointer);
}
}

int readPoints(char* file,int numofpoints)
{
    int i, j;

    POINTS* Pointstructs;
    Pointstructs = (POINTS*)malloc((numofpoints)*sizeof(POINTS));

    if(file == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error transferring file into readPoints\n");
    }

    for(i=0; i<numofpoints; i++)
    {
        fscanf(*file, "%f, %f", &Pointstructs[i].xcord, &Pointstructs[i].ycord);
        printf("%f, %f", Pointstructs[i].xcord, Pointstructs[i].ycord);
    }

    return Pointstructs;
}

int calc(POINTS* points, int numofpoints)
{
    int i=0, j=0;
    int answer;

    while(i<numofpoints && j<numofpoints)
    {
        answer += points[i].xcord * points[j].ycord;
        i++;
        j++;
    }    
return answer;
}
```

Comment: There are multiple places where you should call `exit` and stop execution of the program.

Comment: I always use [Valgrind](https://www.valgrind.org) to find out why I get segfaults. Compile with `-g` and run with `valgrind <program>`. Good luck!

Comment: Are you doing this in a 64-bit system? Remember that `int` is typically still 32 bits, while pointers are 64 bits. Now think again what happens if you cut of the top 32 bits of a pointer and return that value from a function. And turn on warning (if the compiler isn't already shouting warnings at you)!

Comment: In the `calc`  function the variable `answer` is not initialized. And you don't test if `fopen` return `NULL`, which happens if the file could not be opened for some reason. `readPoints` returns an `int` but it should return a `POINTS*`.

Comment: `readPoints()` is returning a pointer to a `POINTS` `struct`, yet the return type is `int`....

Comment: ... and you are multiplying `float` values into `int` product sum.

Comment: short answer: learn how to use your debugger.

Comment: And compiler warnings are your friend.  Turn on all warnings. Why?  Because if the people who wrote the compiler you're using to turn your code into a runnable executable think that what your code is doing is so bad they took the time and put forth the effort to tell you it's a bad idea, you probably should listen to them.  That's a long-winded way of saying "Compiler thinks your code is likely dumb and/or dangerous even if it doesn't violate the language standard."  And it's probably right.

Answer (score 0):

readpoints functions should take its first argument as file pointer BCS fopen returns FILE pointer but u are using char pointer. fscanf first argument should be a file pointer. Pls correct it